# HSM RSA OAEP Encryption with Asymmetric hashes fails

Tags: pkcs#11, pkcs11interop, hardware-security-module

I am using the PKCS11Interop library to Encrypt and Decrypt data with the parameters below.

```
CK_RSA_PKCS_OAEP_PARAMS p = new CK_RSA_PKCS_OAEP_PARAMS();
p.HashAlg = (uint)CKM.CKM_SHA256;
p.Mgf = (uint)CKG.CKG_MGF1_SHA1;
p.Source = (uint)CKZ.CKZ_DATA_SPECIFIED;
p.SourceData = IntPtr.Zero;
p.SourceDataLen = 0;

CK_MECHANISM mech = CkmUtils.CreateMechanism(CKM.CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP, p);
```

The error I get is **CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID** when attempting to Encrypt/Decrypt.
But when I use **CKG_MGF1_SHA256** for **MGF1** then both encryption and decryption works.

Am I missing something or mismatched hashes aren't supported by HSM boxes?

Comment: may be vendor specific.  Who's provider is underneath the interop library?

Comment: @rip... The HSM is NShield Thales - I can't see anything about the MGF1 restriction on the Documentation though.

Comment: k, thx.  Sorry, can't help -- SME for Utimaco CryptoServers, no experience with the Thales equipment.  May be a limitation.  There is another entry in stackoverflow with an answer _That version of HSM simply did not support OAEP with SHA-256_ so this may be a version/supported algo issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the PKCS#1 standard, the random oracles (both hash functions) are identical.

If you want SHA-1, use (uint)CKM.CKM_SHA_1 as hash algorithm.